# Why would setsockopt( TCP_REPAIR ) return EPERM when process has root permission?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a program that will put sockets into `TCP_REPAIR` mode like this:

```
int aux = 1;
if ( setsockopt( mSocket, SOL_TCP, TCP_REPAIR, &aux, sizeof( aux )) < 0 )
{
   showError( "could not turn on repair mode",
              (( errno == EPERM ) ? ( geteuid() ? 
                       ": operation not permitted (not root)" : 
                       ": operation not permitted (...yet running as root)" ) : NULL ));
}
```

This function is returning `EPERM`, even though the process has superuser permissions. The crazy thing about it is that, for socket connections from some clients, this function succeeds, and for some other clients I cannot set `TCP_REPAIR`.

Its as if some clients somehow put the socket into a mode where `TCP_REPAIR` mode is not allowed.

Is there some socket state that `TCP_REPAIR` cant be used? Or some way of connecting that makes it impossible to set `TCP_REPAIR mode`?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I am pretty sure that SELinux can break/stop TCP_REPAIR even for root. Try to disable SELinux just to test if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found an answer. here: http://lwn.net/Articles/495304/

"Changing a process's repair mode status requires the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability; the socket must also either be closed or in the established state."

I wrote a test program to emulate the problem. If the socket opens, writes data, and then closes again before the other side has a chance to put it in repair mode, then it will return EPERM.

Its not a very good way for to deal with it. There really should be some other more explanatory error. But instead they just re-use the EPERM error code.

Comment: Note that since commit https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/319b0534b9588124cdc7128e121f3f85daaab556 `TCP_REPAIR` no longer requires the socket to be in closed or established state. This restriction has been changed to "the socket must be in non-listening (TCP_LISTEN) state".